# Missing BaseGameUtils from google-play-service-lib

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I've installed sucessfully the newer version of google-play-service but I can't find BaseGameUtils. I searched all my folders and it is no where. Anyone with the same problem?I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseGameUtils is published in the [playgamesservices github repository](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries).